# How do I put these different columns into the same row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Here's my dataset (in Hash form since I'm using the Ruby gem Sequel); the hash names are the column names:

```
{:item_category=>"Bacon", :year=>1890, :avg_yr_value=>0.12}
{:item_category=>"Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1890, :avg_yr_value=>0.208}
{:item_category=>"Bacon", :year=>1891, :avg_yr_value=>0.126}
{:item_category=>"Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1891, :avg_yr_value=>0.221}
{:item_category=>"Bacon", :year=>1892, :avg_yr_value=>0.129}
{:item_category=>"Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1892, :avg_yr_value=>0.221}
{:item_category=>"Bacon", :year=>1893, :avg_yr_value=>0.142}
{:item_category=>"Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1893, :avg_yr_value=>0.224}
{:item_category=>"Bacon", :year=>1894, :avg_yr_value=>0.185}
```

Here's my code:

```
    SELECT
        string_agg(DISTINCT item_category, ' + ' ORDER BY item_category) AS items,
        year,
        sum(avg_yr_value) AS amount

    FROM
        earnings_and_prices

    WHERE
        item_category = 'Bacon' OR
            item_category = 'Eggs (dozen)'

    GROUP BY
        year

    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT item_category) = 2

    ORDER BY
        year
```

My result (in hashes since I'm using the Ruby gem Sequel):

```
{:items=>"Bacon + Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1890, :amount=>0.328}
{:items=>"Bacon + Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1891, :amount=>0.347}
{:items=>"Bacon + Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1892, :amount=>0.35}
{:items=>"Bacon + Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1893, :amount=>0.366}
```

I would like to edit my code so it would include the :amount for "Bacon" and the :amount for "Eggs (dozen)", like this for instance:

```
{:items=>"Bacon + Eggs (dozen)", :year=>1890, :amount=>0.328, :eggs_price=>0.208, :bacon_price=>0.12}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: do you mean having individual amount of each item into the _items_ output column, like "10 x Bacon + 20 x Eggs" ?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I've added an example of what I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific scenario, this query fits:

```
SELECT
    item_bacon || ' + ' || item_eggs AS items,
    year,
    bacon_avg_value + eggs_avg_value AS amount,
    bacon_avg_value AS bacon_price, 
    eggs_avg_value AS eggs_price
FROM (
    SELECT t1.item, t2.item, t1.year, t1.avg_value, t2.avg_value
    FROM (
            SELECT item_category, year, avg_yr_value
            FROM earnings_and_prices
            WHERE item_category = 'Bacon'
    ) AS t1(item, year, avg_value)
    JOIN (
            SELECT item_category, year, avg_yr_value
            FROM earnings_and_prices
            WHERE item_category = 'Eggs (dozen)'
    ) AS t2(item, year, avg_value)
    USING( year )
) AS t(item_bacon, item_eggs, year, bacon_avg_value, eggs_avg_value)
ORDER BY year
```

If you need more flexibility (more than two items to filter and show), I'd consider using a dynamic SQL query.

Comment: Yes, this works. I'm a novice at SQL, but I'm understanding better how to do subqueries, and I can see how a subquery in FROM is useful. Two quick questions: What does line 2 mean? What does it mean when you have something like "t(something, something2, something3) -- are you choosing which columns to include?

Comment: @user1626730: You need to give the derived table an alias, hence the `as t1` and `as t2`. If you say `as t(c1, c2, ...)` then you're also naming the columns, if you didn't do that then you'd get `item_category`, `year`, and `avg_yr_value` as the column names for `t1`. `||` is the standard string concatenation operator in SQL so `item_bacon || ' + ' || item_eggs` is like `"#{item_bacon} + #{item_eggs}"` in Ruby.